# search for an object in pgadmin 4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

maybe it's a silly question but in the "ancient" pgadmin 3 there was a tool to search for an object (table, column, trigger function...) based of some pattern. I can't find such tools in pgadmin 4 (I just installed the latest release 4.8) This makes me waste a lot of time. where is it? Is there another way to search or some workaround? thanks in advance! Jacopo.

Comment: You can enable full postgres logging, then perform that search in pgadmin 3, and check the log to see how it does it.

Answer (score 1):

as documented [here](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/search_objects.html), there is such functionality in pgadmin4, you can find it by right-clicking a database inside a server as shown here:

[image: pgAdmin screenshot]